# delete function need write user into useredit

Tags: django-models, django-forms, django-views

every one I got

> models.py

```
....
class ProductsTbl(models.Model):
    .....
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    useredit = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_imagep_Product, blank=True) 

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ''' On save, update timestamps '''

        if not self.id:
            self.created = timezone.now()

        return super(ProductsTbl, self).save(*args, **kwargs)





def get_image_path(instance, filename):
    return '/'.join(['thing_images', instance.thing.slug, filename])


class Upload(models.Model):
    thing = models.ForeignKey(ProductsTbl, related_name="uploads")
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_image_path)   #delete or upload image for this one

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Upload, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.image:
            image = Image.open(self.image)
            i_width, i_height = image.size
            max_size = (640,480)

            if i_width > 1000:
                image.thumbnail(max_size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
                image.save(self.image.path)
```

and I got the views.py function it is for delete the image in class Upload(models.Model) of models.py,

> views.py

```
.....
@login_required
def delete_upload(request, id):
# grab the image

    upload = Upload.objects.get(id=id)


    upload.thing.useredit = request.user.username
    upload.save()
# security check
    # if upload.thing.user != request.user:
    #     raise Http404
# delete the image
    upload.delete()
# refresh the edit page
    return redirect('edit_thing_uploads', slug=upload.thing.slug)
```

what I have to do is when I delete the image I have to write the "user" into the 
"useredit".

however,,when never I delete the image the "user" won't write into "useredit"
,,in contrast,here is my

> edit_thing_uploads.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}
Edit {{ thing.name }}'s Images - {{ block.super }} {% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<h1>Edit {{ thing.name }}'s Images</h1>
<h2>Uploaded images</h2>
{% for upload in uploads %}
<img src="{{ upload.image.url }}" alt="" />
<a href="{% url 'delete_upload' id=upload.id  %}">Delete</a>
{% endfor %}
<h2>Upload a new image</h2>
<form role="form" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

when I upload an image it will write "user" into "useredit" successfully ,,the function for upload image in

> views.py

```
@login_required
def edit_thing_uploads(request, slug):
# grab the object...
    thing = ProductsTbl.objects.get(slug=slug)
# double checking just for security
    # if thing.user != request.user:
    #     raise Http404

    form_class = ProductsTblUploadForm
# if we're coming to this view from a submitted form,
    if request.method == 'POST':
# grab the data from the submitted form, # note the new "files" part
        form = form_class(data=request.POST,files=request.FILES, instance=thing)
        if form.is_valid():
            thing = form.save(commit=False)
            thing.useredit = request.user.username
            thing.save()
# create a new object from the submitted form
            Upload.objects.create(
                image=form.cleaned_data['image'],
                thing=thing,
            )
            return redirect('edit_thing_uploads', slug=thing.slug)
# otherwise just create the form
    else:
        form = form_class(instance=thing)
# grab all the object's images
    uploads = thing.uploads.all()
# and render the template
    return render(request, 'things/edit_thing_uploads.html', {
        'thing': thing,
        'form': form,
        'uploads': uploads,
    })
```

however,,I have to let the "user" into "useredit" when I delete also,,,how can I do it? thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem

> views.py

```
@login_required
def delete_upload(request, id):
# grab the image
    upload = Upload.objects.get(id=id)
    upload.thing.useredit = request.user.username
    upload.thing.save()
# security check
    # if upload.thing.user != request.user:
    #     raise Http404
# delete the image
    upload.delete()
# refresh the edit page
    return redirect('edit_thing_uploads', slug=upload.thing.slug)
```